# Highchart gauge: How to change tick position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am implementing Highchart gauge(speedometer) to display internet bandwidth speed. I want points to be display in following sequence [0,1,2,5,10,25,50,100,500]. But if I use this sequence my speedometer looks like below screenshot

[image: My highchart gauge]

I couldn't able to give space between points. Is there any way to plot the points at equal distance like below image

[image: Expected gauge]

```
Here is the jsfiddle that illustrates the problem.
```

[highchart gauge jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/31/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Makarand Patil was saying, a logarithmic axis is necessary.

To achive that and put the ticks where desired, you can use the following `yAxis` options:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 1,
  max: 500,
  type: 'logarithmic',
  minorTickInterval: 'auto',
  tickPositions: [0, Math.log10(2), Math.log10(5), Math.log10(10), Math.log10(25), Math.log10(50), Math.log10(100), Math.log10(500)],
  ...
```

Also note that every value in the plot needs to be > 0. If you assign a 0 value, it will fail. I changed the number generation to take that into account in the example.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/33/

**API on yAxis.type:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

---

Update to answer comment regarding displaying 0 first.

To display a 0 in the graph we need to cheat, since logarithmic axes don't have 0 values. I made the zero appear like this:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0.499,
  tickPositions: [Math.log10(0.5),Math.log10(1), Math.log10(2), Math.log10(5), Math.log10(10), Math.log10(25), Math.log10(50), Math.log10(100), Math.log10(500)]
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if(this.value === 0.5){
        return 0;
      } else {
        return this.value;
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Basically, we set 0.5 as 0 because we don't want to have the values from 0 to 1 fill too much of the chart. Then we change the labels on the axis so that the label saying 0.5 will infarct say 0.

Not that values in this graph would need to be between 0.5 and 500. Where we approximate 0.5 to be 0.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/36/

**Working example, with fixed arrow:** http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/37/

Comment: thanks a lot @ewolden. Your solution is working. I want to display 0 as well just before 1. In this case, what should I assign to the **min**.

Comment: Thank you **@ewolden**. I have one more doubt, you might have seen in jsfiddle the needle position after page load. The needle is appearing horizontally on top of gauge and after few seconds showing on right place. any idea why it is behaving like that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/37/ fixed it, it was because `y: 0` was set for the datapoint on load.

Comment: Thanks again for all :-) **@ewolden**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `type: 'logarithmic'` in your `yAxis: {...}` to adjust space between your points with various other logical changes.

Look at this fiddle with similar type of highchart :  http://jsfiddle.net/5x8cmvy7/.

Comment: Thank you @makarand. but still, I am struggling to achieve above point sequence (0,1,2,5,10,25,50,100,500). Find my updated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8cz9m9c8/35/